# Apply usbhid quirks

Tags: linux-mint, kernel-module, usb-hid

I have device 0x56a:0x350 (wacom cintiq pro 16) which accidentally (due to hardware issue), it's read by the system (on any machine or OS) as 0x56a:0x34e (wacom MobileStudio Pro 16)

It's working fine, but the pen X and Y are inverted, so I would like to do one of three things:

1. patch the hid report descriptor of the device to provide the correct information about itself to the kernel usbhid module (but I don't have hex dump of the correct hid descriptor of the 0x350 device) - if anyone can tell where to find it.
2. apply usbhid quirk HID_DG_INVERT (0x000d003c) which inverts x and y (but I don't know where/how to apply such quirk during the module load especially that usbhid is configured in my system as builtin)
3. apply libinput quirk which inverts the X and Y (which is the easiest option, but I don't know what would be the quirk that can do this if any)

if anyone can help me with one of the two options (or any other suggestions) then this would be appreciated.

Comment: `if anyone can help me` is not a question about the problem ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... this site is not a brainstorming forum

Comment: There are three questions!! I ask if anyone can help me by answering any of them:
1. Where can I find the report descriptor of Wacom Cintiq Pro 16 (0x56a:0x350)?
2. How to apply usbhid quirk during kernel module load?
3. Is there a libinput quirk that can invert X and Y?